# JQuery multiple select control with css class in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: jquery

I am working in an ASP.Net MVC 4 application. In a view, i have multiple html select controls with different class name in a form tag. Currently, i'm getting those as follows-

```
 $('select', form).each(function () {

});
```

But, i would like to catch select element with their class name also. Here is a pseudocode-

```
 $(select which has classA in form).each(function () {

});
```

What is the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
         $(#form_id select.myclass).each(function () {

         });
```

HTML CODE

```
<form id="form_id">
    <select class="myclass">
        <option>A</option>
        ....
    </select>
</form>
```